# Can I open remote datasets with Rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, rioxarray

I know I can open remote datasets with GDAL, I was wondering if I can do the same with Rasterio?

GDAL bindings code of what I mean by opening remote dataset:

```py
import gdal
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

mmap_name = '/vsicurl/https://esgf.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/fileServer/BioClim/WRE/bio11_equiv_2053.tiff'
dataset = gdal.Open(mmap_name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Rasterio is a Python wrapper for GDAL, so it should be able to read in anything that the GDAL can.

Here is an example of opening a remote file with rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/COG.html

```py
import rioxarray

mmap_name = 'https://esgf.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/fileServer/BioClim/WRE/bio11_equiv_2053.tiff'
dataset = rioxarray.open_rasterio(mmap_name)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can open remote dataset with Rasterio. It's really similar to GDAL like illustrated below

```py
import rasterio

mmap_name = '/vsicurl/https://esgf.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/fileServer/BioClim/WRE/bio11_equiv_2053.tiff'
# Note: the following works too, at least for tif (other remote data source untested)
# mmap_name = 'https://esgf.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/fileServer/BioClim/WRE/bio11_equiv_2053.tiff'

with rasterio.open(mmap_name) as src: 
    print(src.width, src.height)
```